# First start - custom windowBackground splash color

Tags: android, styles, themes

I'm using the `windowBackground` splash screen approach (I want the first visible impression to fit my apps theme) AND I allow to use custom themes in my app, so the window background can be changed I can't set a theme in my app with the correct `windowBackground` because the user can change this theme.

When opening my app, I will always see the default windowBackground color, coming from my light theme, the one I set in the manifest. My manifest looks like following:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeLight" >

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.mvp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

In my activity, I overwrite the theme like following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setTheme(...); // setting user selected theme, AppThemeLight or AppThemeDark
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

When starting the app, I ALWAYS see the light splash screen comming from my "AppThemeLight", even if using `setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark)` when creating the activity...

Can I somehow change the main theme of my application in code? Or any other trick to get this working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try below thing will not shown light theme on startup and change your activity theme on user selection.

- Remove application level theme from your manifest file.
- Set theme from activity base on your user selection.

As I have tried setting theme from application object but it not taking that theme(I am not sure why).

But if you remove that theme from application (manifest). You will have to set theme for your all activities explicitly.

Comment: This is not working for me. By the way, setting the theme for the activity is working perfectly fine already, I'm just talking about the short time on the first app start, where you see a white background before the activity draws itself... I want this first impression to be light or dark, depending on the users selected theme...